# Amazon app store Android Java.Lang.VerifyError cant replicate

Tags: android, app-store, appstore-approval, amazon-appstore

I have submitted an app to the Amazon app store.  It has been rejected twice now for the same reason, but I can't find the problem.  It crashes right at the start, usually 2-3 activity windows in.  This error never happens on our test devices, and there hasn't been a single error or crash from the app on the Google market. So thus far I've been completely unable to replicate the error.

On the last rejection we requested a stacktrace, which they sent, but only with errors, not warnings, which from what I gather is what I need to find out exactly what method is causing the `Java.Lang.VerifyError` from W/dalvikvm.  Is it reasonable to assume that when they decompile the app, and inject their amazon drm/tracking/whatever code into the app, and recompile it, it's causing clashing errors with some of my code? or that Amazon are possibly compiling on a different version of Java than we are? (ours is 1.6)

The app has both minSDK and targetSDK set to api8, which is 2.2 minimum, and we compile it against 2.2, Has anyone else had this error with Amazon before and might be able to give me some insight as to how the problem was resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any Java 1.6 methods? Maybe String.isEmpty()? It's going to be nearly impossible to help you without a bit more info.

Comment: Not using any String.isEmpty() or anything, mostly just @override.
Sorry about the lack of info, i can barely help myself with what little information i get out of Amazon. This problem seems to me to be one that cant be solved by looking at code, but rather by someone who has had the same experience with the review team at Amazon Appstore and had their problem resolved.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I can't ever reproduce their error (2 separate apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. In the Manifest there was a .java file that was declared as an activity, which it was originally, but it had been changed to extend Dialog instead.

When Amazon injects code into your app, they look at the manifest to find the Android Activities, and inject code into them such as callbacks and method overrides, some of which are specific to the Activity class. When Amazon looked at my manifest, they thought the class was an Activity, but it was actually now a Dialog, and the app was crashing when trying to override methods that didn't exist.

Once removing the manifest declarations to the classes that weren't actual Activities, the app got approved. Its weird that google and eclipse didn't pick up on the declared activities that weren't activities when the app got compiled.

Hope this can help others who cant seem to find out the reason their apps not getting approved by Amazon.